# Unable to install dplyr in R 3.3.1

Tags: r

I can't seem to install dplyr or perhaps I really can't install it?
Here's what  I have

```
install.packages("dplyr")
package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘C:/Users/808797/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpkl7AKB/downloaded_packages’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

also tried

```
>install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/dplyr_0.5.0.zip",repos=null,type=source)
```

also tried

```
> library("downloader")
> download("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/dplyr_0.5.0.zip","dplyr")
> install.packages("dplyr")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

always the same  `is not available (for R version 3.3.1)`

am i out of luck?

Comment: post your ``sessionInfo()``

Comment: try picking other repository and try it.

Comment: @user5249203 yup i sure did.

Comment: are you behind firewall ?

Comment: @user5249203 i am at work so im sure there is... but everything else is installed...

Comment: hmm..thats interesting. Why don't you take a manual route..http://stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/bugsR/alternate_install.html

Comment: so i forced it in manually by putting dragging it into the library folder... I don't want to put this as the answer though.

Comment: That is also wrong. What you _could_ do is `download.file()` followed by install from local source. _You want the install step._

Comment: yeap, try download the zip file and `setwd` to that folder. `install.packages("dplyr", repos = "null")`

Answer (score 3):

It is likely your network, or network connection.  This is a widely-used package, and I just fired up Virtual Box to demonstrate that, in general, this works as expected.

[image]

Things you *could* try are *e.g.* downloading something and then checking the md5sum via `tools::md5sum()`.

Otherwise, look at the R-on-Windows FAQ and check *e.g.* [question 2.19](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#The-Internet-download-functions-fail_002e) which recommends proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is a two step procedure
1] `install.packages("assertthat")`
2] search google dplyr_0.4.1.tar.gz ..download it from CRAN archives or somewhere ..while in RStudio Tools>InstallPackage(install via archive) ..browse to the .tar.gz ...initiate installation

Comment: Hardly a "solution".  Every CRAN package should be directly installable on current R version.  If it is not, take that as a *strong* symptom that something is cooked at your end.

Comment: NO ..the package management sometimes require specific R version, one thus is forced to install previous package version ..that is compatible with an older R version residing in your PC. I know this nifty hack because Debian user usually are bounded by older package versions

Comment: You are confusing a couple of things.  First remark, my remark was for _CRAN_ where everything _current_ is installable.  Running Debian and installing its r-cran-* packages is a choice you.  I _maintain_ dozens of those, but when I want _current_ version I often go with CRAN installation.  It's a choice, and in your case apparently an ill-informed one as [this README at CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/) tells you to get _current R builds_ for your Debian releases. I have relied on this (and the matching Ubuntu builds) for a decade or longer on production systems.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to download some package behind a proxy, without a correct configuration. I think that the error message is quite confusing!

For future readers, to solve this problem with RStudio on Linux you should create a file `touch ~/.Renviron` in your home, edit this file adding you proxy config `vim ~/.Renviron` (set variables `http_proxy=` and `https_proxy=`, each in a different row), then start/restart Rstudio. This should work.

[Reference](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-or-HTTPS-Proxy)